# Crystal Reports creates multiple page

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report, it has a 1 page report. when i tried to click print button to print, i noticed that it generates 8400 pages. What's wrong with that?!

Comment: Please verify the height-width, margin of each section.

Comment: how can i verify the height-width, margin? thank... I'm new to vb.NET and crystal reports. Thanks!

Comment: Does your crystal reports contain subReports? If yes, In which section have you placed it? (i.e. in detail section, header section etc.)

Comment: Are you saying the report preview is one page and only when you print it generates 8400 pages? What about an export to pdf?

Comment: yes i have subreport... it is located at the bottom of the page!

Comment: even in the preview it generates 8400 pages... i just noticed it when i tried to print the report..

Comment: You didn't mention the content... is it printing what it should?  Are the 8400+ pages blank?  Try suppressing the subreport and look at the preview.  If it's a single page, we may know where the problem lies.

Comment: It does print what it should print. On the first page all the details are there... second page black then third page it repeats what's in page one the blank then repeart and so on till 8400...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. I put all in the Details section. I just divide my report in the different part of the crystal report page and just put the necessary details in the Details Section.

Thanks guys for your answer... God bLess :)

Answer (score 0):

If the preview has 1 page but prints 8k then it may be a problem with the print driver.
Can you print it to another device or the XPS document printer and check the number of pages there?